# How do you fix time out error in Synergy?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, windows-8.1, synergy

I am trying to control my Ubuntu laptop with keyboard and mouse that I use with my Windows laptop. Everything works fine when I set up my Ubuntu laptop as a server and then connect to it with my windows laptop but when I try to do the oposite and use my windows laptop as a server, on my Ubuntu laptop i get an error saying:
"WARNING: failed to connect to server: Timed out"
Has anyone encountered similar problem? And if yes does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you configure the Windows Firewall accordingly?

Comment: What do you mean by configure it accordingly

Comment: if you're using the Windows Firewall you would have to create a rule which would allow other computers to connect to the server on your PC. You probably need to define a port for that server and if that port is not open for your laptop the connection is going to fail.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: For a test you could just open your firewall settings and disable it temporarily, that way you could test whenever that is the problem. It's not unusual to get a popup as well that asks how you want an application to be able to communicate. Otherwise open the advanced options and create a new inbound rule that matches your application. [HowToGeek HowTo](http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the computers can't see each other, usually because of a firewall. Make sure both computers are on the same network and temporarily disable the firewall on the server computer (don't forget to re-enable once you're finished).

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add my answer for fixing this issue as I kept finding this page when searching for this problem.

Server: W10
Client: W10
Synergy v1.13.1 Pro

After verifying that both computers were able to communicate to each other (ruling out the firewall issue by using ping <local ip address> )...

I navigated to C:\Users\ <username> \AppData\Local\Synergy\SSL\Fingerprints\ 
Modified the file TrustedServers by removing the fingerprint.

I restarted both synergy services and basically forced them get a new fingerprint to resolve the issue.